# Statically linking libtcod

Tags: c++, libtcod

I'm trying to statically link [libtcod](http://doryen.eptalys.net/libtcod/) to my C++ project without success. I get many linking errors, including:

./tuto: error while loading shared libraries: libtcodxx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Has anyone had similar problems with that library?

Answer (score 1):

There are dynamic libs provided in current libtcod (1.6.0) distribution.
You can link libtcod dynamically, but you need to create symbolic links:

```
    cd /var/lib/libtcod
    ln -s libtcod.so libtcod.so.1
    ln -s libtcodxx.so libtcodxx.so.1
```

Compile with following command:

```
    g++ src/*.cpp -o tuto -I/var/lib/libtcod/include -L/var/lib/libtcod -ltcod -ltcodxx -Wl,-rpath=/var/lib/libtcod -Wall
```

Answer (score 0):

Which flags do you use while linking to the library? Did you used `-static` flag, do you specified `-ltcod`? If not, add `-static -ltcod` to the end of command line.
Or you can **force** tell gcc to link with static builded library:
`gcc %YOUR_OTHER_FLAGS_ANDFILES% -l:libtcod.a -L%PATH_TO_TCOD_STATIC_BUILDED_FILE%`

Comment: I have used the following: g++ src/*.cpp -o tuto -I/var/lib/libtcod/include -L/var/lib/libtcod -ltcod -ltcodxx -Wl,-rpath=. -Wall -static

Comment: I have cloned libtcod and compiled it for Linux, 32 bit. Located on /var/lib/libtcod

Comment: try this: `g++ src/*.cpp -o tuto -I/var/lib/libtcod/include -L/var/lib/libtcod -l:/var/lib/libtcod.a -l:/var/lib/libtcodxx.a -Wl,-rpath=. -Wall`